# AADSTS700016 Adal problem with wrong tenant directory

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory, adal, adal.js

I am having a problem with my react application and authentication with adal-ms-react [(link)](https://github.com/nishch/react-ms-login). I followed up installation but run into a problem with code AADSTS700016. This suggests that my tenant directory is not correct, which definitely is not (I can see it where I registered my app on Azure portal.

Problem is I have no idea where to set my correct directory in my react app. There is a place for client ID and redirectURL but no tenant or tenantId.

[image: loginMSSPecs]

Anybody having knowledge where to set it up so it refers to correct directory?
This resource looks like is old 2 years, maybe that is the problem?

Comment: Where did you register your application?

Comment: In the Azure portal under Azure active directory

Comment: @TomášTomHaverla If my answer is helpful for you, please make it as answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, solved my problem. Apologies for late reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to configure the tenant information since this react app is a multi-tenant application. You can find its oauthUrl  in `index.jsx` file. It's using common, not specific tenant.

```
this.oauthUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize";
```

You can find more details of multi-tenant [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant).

Besides, the auth url is using v2.0 endpoint. So you need to register your app in [Microsoft App Dev Center](https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/#/appList). If you want to register your app in Azure portal, you need to register it under App registrations(Preview) which applies to v2.0 endpoint.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting this error is because the application is registered in wrong place. You're making use of Azure AD v2.0 endpoint and the application using this needs to be registered at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com/ and not Azure Portal. Azure Portal should be used to register applications targeting Azure AD v1.0 endpoints.

To learn more about registering an app with the Azure AD v2.0 endpoint, please see this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-v2-register-an-app.

Comment: This is no longer correct. You *are* supposed to use the Azure Portal. See this blog post https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/identity/blogs/deprecation-of-app-registrations-legacy-experience-and-the-application-registration-portal-apps-dev-microsoft-com/